# BigQuery - Converting an ID from base 10 to base 36

Tags: google-bigquery

How to convert a base 10 id into a base 36 id in google big query.

Example: 
4503599684322375 -> should convert to -> 18ce54sjpl3

[Link to converter](http://www.unitconversion.org/numbers/base-10-to-base-36-conversion.html)

In MySQL, I've used the below but can seem to find any options for this in BQ

`CONV(num , from_base , to_base );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to perform this conversion, you should use a [JavaScript UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#javascript-udf-structure) with the JS method [toString(36)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp), which will allow you to convert to a String encoded in base 36.

The syntax is as follows:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION tobase36(x NUMERIC)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
 return (x).toString(36);
""";
#test with sample data
WITH data AS (
SELECT 4503599684322375 AS base10
)
SELECT base10, tobase36(base10) AS base36 FROM data
```

And the output,

```
Row base10            base36    
1   4503599684322375  18ce54sjpl3
```

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. I tried running that but i got an error "Templated js UDFs are not yet supported, but function tobase36 has a templated parameter"

Comment: @ConorJohnston, I have changed one thing. When creating the UDF the type it receives must be ***NUMERIC*** not **ANY TYPE**. I had tested with the right type and the output is as described in the answer.

Comment: Works perfectly now. You're a life saver. Thank you!

Comment: @ConorJohnston, please consider uprooting and accepting the answer. Thanks !